# Locating Welsh 1939 Register information that is referred to in "See INSTRUCTIONS" column

Tags: wales, 1930s, national-registration

How can I locate the information this Welsh 1939 Register entry refers to for Esme Harris?

[image]

I acquired the scanned document when I had a subscription with Ancestry. I now notice that in the **See INSTRUCTIONS** column there is a note:

> See Page 12 BK 2.

How can I find this? I don't currently have any paid subscription.

Comment: I've been tempted to flag this as a duplicate of [How can we find a record that we see on Ancestry on another website?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/18020/10577)

Comment: @shoover Up to you my friend. Does that answer explain how to locate the book / page referred to in the entries note?

Comment: No, just that you might have some luck getting access through the library, which answers only half your question.

Comment: I would test it, but the library I work at is an academic library and doesn't give me access to Ancestry. My public library gives access to Ancestry, but only when I'm connected to their network, i.e. onsite at the library.

Comment: MyHeritage is available offsite and has UK records but only the index for the 1939 registry, not the images.

Comment: @shoover I have a login to our library version. I can try. But how do I get to this book 2 it references?

Comment: IMO this is not a duplicate of the "find the record elsewhere" question. This is a question about how to interpret the information in the left-most column of the right-hand page of the 1939 Register and navigate within the collection. The fact that Andrew doesn't currently have a paid sub with Ancestry is a red herring.  If my answer is acceptable, I suggest that the reference to not having an Ancestry sub be edited out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

From The National Archives' Research Guide on the [1939 Register](https://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/help-with-your-research/research-guides/1939-register/):

> **8. What does it mean when an entry is crossed out and marked ‘See page…?’**
>
> These refer to ‘continuation entries’ where the line in the
> ‘postings’ column (see section 9.3) against a person’s name was full
> up, and a new line had to be created for any new entries.
>
> The new line was added at the back of the enumeration book or
> sometimes at the back of the next book in large enumeration districts
> that comprised two or more books. You can browse to the page
> containing the continuation entry if it is in the same book; if it is
> in the next book you can use the browse function described in section
> 5.2 to go there, and then browse to the right page. However, this is very unlikely to contain any additional information.

To read the other sections of the Guide researched in this snippet, please refer to the guide at TNA, which is linked above.

For navigating on Ancestry, go to the main collection page:
[1939 England and Wales Register](https://www.ancestry.com/search/collections/61596/)

Look at the right-hand side of the page where it says **Browse this collection** and use the drop-down boxes to choose the appropriate district.

- Carmarthenshire
- Llanelly Mb
- Xdhe

From there, you can browse the entire enumeration district.

However, in this case, it is more straightforward to search. There are two results.

- https://www.ancestry.com/sharing/29142445?h=636930 (image 12)
- https://www.ancestry.com/sharing/29142463?h=c6023d (image 27)

The first link is the image posted above. The second is likely to be the continuation entry referenced in the TNA guide.

> ```
>  Record ID    61596::40669949
>  URL  https://www.ancestry.com/discoveryui-content/view/40669949:61596
>  Name Esme Harries
>  Gender   Female
>  Marital Status   Widowed
>  Birth Date    20 April 1887
>  Residence Date    1939
>  Address  24 Gocing Road
>  Residence Place  Llanelly, Carmarthenshire, Wales
>  Occupation   Unpaid Domestic Duties
>  Line Number  1
>  Schedule Number  136
>  Sub Schedule Number  1
>  Enumeration District Xdhe
>  Borough  Llanelly
>  Household Members    This record is officially closed., This record is officially closed.
>  Source.Title 1939 England and Wales Register
>  Source.Part1 The National Archives
>  Source.Part2 Kew, London, England
>  Source.Part3 1939 Register
>  Source.Reference Rg 101/7206j
>  Source.Citation  The National Archives; Kew, London, England; 1939 Register; Reference: Rg 101/7206j
> ```

Ancestry Record Page information copied using John Cardinal's [Online Respository Assistant (ORA)](https://www.ora-extension.com/en/index.htm#/).

Once you have accesss to Ancestry again, do a search and you'll be able to get the image for the continuation entry.

**findmypast**

At findmypast, the two books are listed separately, but both were easily found as part of a global search. Since you already have the enumeration district, it would be more straightforward to search from the collection search page: [1939 Register](https://search.findmypast.com/search-world-records/1939-register)

**MyHeritage**

On MyHeritage, searching from the collection page: [1939 Register of England & Wales](https://www.myheritage.com/research/collection-10678/1939-register-of-england-wales?s=25865711) gave both pages as the top two entries.